# How do I make reportlab pdf generator ignore < or > symbols

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

I am trying to put together a pdf document using reportlab.  When I try to write out a line with < or > symbols the text disappears because reportlab's paragraph support xml tags.  How do I disable this behavior?  A lot of my text is math forumlas that contain < or > symbols  Here is an example of what I'm talking about...

```
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet

styles = getSampleStyleSheet()

def page_one(canvas, doc):
    canvas.saveState()
    canvas.setFont('Helvetica',12)
    canvas.restoreState()

def main():
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate("example.pdf")
    Story = list()
    style = styles["Normal"]
    example_disappear = u'this is visible <this text is not visible> this is visible'
    p = Paragraph(example_disappear, style)
    Story.append(p)
    doc.build(Story, onFirstPage=page_one)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I want to be able to use < or > symbols without having the text between them disappear.

EDIT:
martineau got me on the right track.  I looked at some of the xml utilities available through python and found a few parsers.  The python xml module has an escape function so I just added this line...

```
from xml.sax.saxutils import escape
```

and modified my Paragraph to this...

```
p = Paragraph(escape(example_disappear), style)
```

And the text is visible.

Comment: Try using `&lt;` and `&gt;` in place of < and >.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I tried what you suggested and got.. this is visible &ltthis text is not visible> this is visible.  It's halfway there.